# Installing visual studio 2012 ultimate on Windows Server 2012 Giving me ERROR

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installation, sharepoint-2013, windows-server-2012

I am trying to install `Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate` version on `Windows Server 2012 Release Candidate Datacenter`.

And Visual Studio giving me this error.

```
The .Net Framework installed on this machine does not meet the minimum required version: 4.5.50709.
```

Please help me that what can I do to solve this?
And if I have to change the version which Visual Studio should I have to install.
Please let me know that which version I have to use of Visual Studio.

I had also tried to give permission in
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\NET FRAMEWORK SETUP\NDP\v4\full\1033`
But it is giving me access denied error, though I am admin user.

Please Help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you have to give administrator rights to that folder.

You have to create new group and give that group administrator rights and assign that group to that folder.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\NET FRAMEWORK SETUP\NDP\v4
```

Answer (score 2):

Most likely related to the following

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfssetup/thread/07cfd620-0599-42dc-bdf8-fe04fb11bff8

looks as if you have to install the trial rather than the RC

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/hh670538.aspx?EP=200072478

Comment: But this that post show me that I have to download Windows Server. Is there anything that for visual studio version is supported in this OS that I have installed.?

Comment: You could try and see if there's a .net 4.5 update out there that'll install, but sadly it doesn't seem like it

Comment: Yes you might be right. But I have to start developing with SharePoint 2013. And for that I'll need both Studio 2012 and Server 2012.

Comment: You could try the following, although it seems unlikely that it will work   http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36377